# Apache hive with microsoft odbc

Tags: apache, hive

I would like to connect QlikSense(Business Intelligence software) which runs on Microsoft Server 2008 to Apache Hive Server. My hive is running on Red Hat linux.

I have downloaded the Microsoft ODBC.
I have also configured the hive-site.xml.

I need to know is there any other files in Apache Hive that I need to configure or is there any other way that i can do to connect the Microsoft ODBC with Apache Hive.

I would really appreciate your responses. Thank you.

Comment: What issues do you have? Could you create ODBC datasource? What is your version of Apache Hive?

Comment: I have downloaded the Cloudera ODBC but when I tested the connection, it fails

Comment: My Apache Hive version is 0.12.0

Comment: There is server interface that allows remote clients to execute Hive queries and retrieve the results. </br>
Technically, there are two versions: [HiveServer1](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/HiveServer) and [HiveServer2](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/Setting+Up+HiveServer2). The last one is used in the newer versions of Hive. As your version is 0.12.0, there is Hive ODBC driver provided as a part of your Apache Hive for HiveServer1. So you can try it..